# jquery trouble with not() and dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have a horizontal list menu which when clicked toggles the visibility of a nested list. the function almost works, i click the menu and the visibility toggles. however, when i click inside the element that has just appeared, the visibility of the nested list reverts back to original state and is hidden. this is a bit difficult when the elements require an interaction (whether it's a form or another menu).

Here's the code i've got so far:

```
/*  menu */
var menu = function(clicktarget, dropdown){
    $(clicktarget).click( function(event){
        // stop bubbling
        event.stopPropagation();
        //show
        $(dropdown).toggle();
        return false;
    });

    $('body').not($(dropdown)).click( function(){
        //hide when click anywhere out the menu
        $(dropdown).hide();
        return false;
    });
}
menu($('#loginAcc'),$('#auth-menu'));
```

As you can see i have tried using the .not() function in an attempt to remove it, but nothing changes and the dropdown still gets removed when it's clicked.

Comment: Can you provide a Jsfiddle of you code.

Comment: Just FYI, the value of `dropdown` (and `clicktarget`) is already a jQuery object, so there is no reason to pass it to jQuery *again*. It the same as doing : `$($('#auth-menu')).hide()` which is rather odd.

Comment: `$('body').not($(dropdown)).click(...)` basically means: Select all `body` elements (of which there is only one btw) and remove all elements that equal to `dropdown`, i.e. all elements with ID `#auth-menu`. I assume the `body` element does not have that ID, hence it won't be removed from the selection. Then the click event handler is bound to the `body` element. This is not the right way to ignore an event that has originated within a specific element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('body').click( function(e){
    //hide when click anywhere out the menu
    var $target  = $(e.target)
    if(!$target.closest(dropdown).length){
        $(dropdown).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```